# React app not sending the refresh token stored in cookie?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, mern

i am trying to implement the access token refreshment through refresh token which is send via cookie . but my frontend react app is not sending it back to the server or it is not storing the refresh token in its cookie as a result i get response.cookies.cookie_name as a undefined
. it works when i remove the withCredentials but it doesnot when i set it .

i have tested my server in postman and it works fine.

my Backend Login code

```
exports.login = catchAsync(async (request, response, next) => {
  const { email, password } = request.body;
  if (!email || !password)
    return next(new AppError("Email and password required"));

  const document = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (
    !document ||
    !(await document.comparePassword(password, document.password))
  )
    return next(new AppError("Email or password incorrect"));

  const accessToken = issueJWT.issueAccessToken({ _id: document._id });
  const refreshToken = issueJWT.issueRefreshToken({ _id: document._id }); 

  response.cookie("auth", refreshToken, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "None",
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  });

  response.status(200).json({
    message: "Logged in successfully",
    accessToken,
    document,
  });
});
```

Cors Setup

```
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000", credentials: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
```

my frontend axios setup

```
import store from "../Store";
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const privateInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1",
});

privateInstance.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  let accessToken = store.getState().User.accessToken;
  request.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  return request;
});
export default privateInstance;
```

Comment: have you tried setting response header 'Set-Cookie'?
example how I set cookies from my NestJS server:  `ctx.res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [ 'x-access-token=' + tokens.access_token +  '; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/; SameSite=None; Max-Age=' + tokens.exp])`

Comment: Yes I tried but didn't work .